# Replacing text except in the URL

Tags: ruby, regex

Say that we have the following text

```
example abc http://www.example.com
```

I know how to replace `example` by some text for instance. But, when I do that, how can I tell the program NOT to substitute the `example` in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

@kiddorails reminded me of a [known trick](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) to work around a missing variable-width look-behind that can be implemented in Ruby as well. However, the regex used by @kiddorails will not replace `example` before the URL. Also, it is not dynamic.

Here is a function that will replace specific words (whole word mode is enforced by using `\b`s, but they can be removed in case you need to match strings with non-word leading and trailing characters) not in an URL even if they contain symbols that must be escaped in a regex:

```
def removeOutsideOfURL(word, input)
   rx = Regexp.new("(?i)\\b" + Regexp.escape(word.reverse) + "(?!\\S+ptth\\b)")
   return input.reverse.gsub(rx,"").reverse
end

puts removeOutsideOfURL("example", "example def http://www.example.com with a new example")
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWUhoWVRjSm5MOEk):

```
def http://www.example.com with a new
```

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

For this concrete example and context, you can use `(?<!http:\/\/www\.)example/`:

```
puts "example def http://www.example.com".gsub(/(?<!http:\/\/www\.)example/, '')
>> def http://www.example.com
```

[Demo on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/2NentB)

You can add more look-behinds to set more conditions, e.g. `/(?<!http:\/\/www\.)(?<!http:\/\/)example/` to also keep `example` straight after `http://`.

Or, you can also check for periods on both ends:

```
(?<!\.)example(?!\.)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution on this text: "example http://www.example.o.org/example_docs", and the "second" 'example' in the URL was selected. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I think this may be a solution to that ---> (?<!http:\/\/www.)(?<!http:\/\/www.example.o.org.)example

Comment: @Simplicity: When you pass `example http://example.o.org/example_docs`, the result is `http://example.o.org/example_docs`. Isn't it expected? If you only want to keep `example` right after `http://` or `http://www.`, use `/(?<!http:\/\/www\.)(?<!http:\/\/)example/i` regex (`i` = case insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub`:

```
"example def http://www.example.com".sub("example","")
```

Result:

```
" def http://www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Pointers by @stribizhev :)

For this particular use case, I will go along with **negative lookbehind regex** as @stribizhev used above.
But there is one gotcha with negative lookbehind regex - **It only accepts fixed length regex**.

So, if urls are like: http://example.com or http://www.example.com, the check can either pass for first case or last.
I suggest this approach - reverse the url, use **negative lookahead** regex and substitute reverse of "example" in your string. Here is the demo below:

```
regex = /elpmaxe(?!\S+ptth)/
str1 = "example http://example.com"
str2 = "example http://www.example.com"
str3 = "foo example http://wwww.someexampleurl.com"
str4 = "example def http://www.example.com with a new example"
[str1, str2, str3, str4].map do |str|
  str.reverse.gsub(regex, '').reverse
end
#=>[" http://example.com",
 " http://www.example.com",
 "foo  http://wwww.someexampleurl.com", 
 " def http://www.example.com with a new "]
```